# Picking Up Items in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I am implementing an FPS game and I'm trying to set up an Inventory System, such that when I look at an Item it is picked up and saved in my inventory. The issue is that I can't seem to pick up/destroy only **one** item. All items are getting destroyed. The following script is attached to the item I am testing this on.

The inspector image of the item is the following: [image]

The script attached to the item is as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUpItems : MonoBehaviour
{

    Inventory invScript;
    public bool item;
    public int distanceToItem;
    public Camera fpCamera;
  //  public GameObject itemIcon;

    bool pickedUp = false;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        fpCamera = Camera.main;
        invScript = GameObject.FindWithTag("GameController").GetComponent<Inventory>();
    } //Start

    private void Update()
    {
        Collect();
    }

    void Collect()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && !pickedUp)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = fpCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, distanceToItem))
            {
                if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Food")
                {
                    Debug.Log("pickedup");
                    pickedUp = true;
                    StartCoroutine("AddItem");
                    //play sound here
                }
            }
        }
    } //Collect


    IEnumerator AddItem()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        //GameObject i = Instantiate(itemIcon);
        //i.transform.SetParent(invScript.inventoryPanel.transform);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    } //AddItem


} //class
```

I would appreciate very it if someone could help with such an issue!

Comment: "The following script is attached to the item I am testing this on" is attached to your item o to your PlayerController?

Comment: @Lotan It is attached to the item, in the case ''Small Food Can''

Comment: This question is not an appropriate use of [tag:visual-studio].

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've made it so that each `PickUpItems` is only concerned if the camera is looking at any can. I also recommend making `distanceToItem` a float:

```
                if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Food")
                {
                    Debug.Log("pickedup");
                    pickedUp = true;
                    StartCoroutine("AddItem");
                    //play sound here
                }
```

Instead, you should consider making each `PickUpItems` concerned if the camera is pointing at the `PickUpItems` itself.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUpItems : MonoBehaviour
{

    Inventory invScript;
    public bool item;
    public float distanceToItem;
    public Camera fpCamera;
  //  public GameObject itemIcon;

    bool pickedUp = false;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        fpCamera = Camera.main;
        invScript = GameObject.FindWithTag("GameController").GetComponent<Inventory>();
    } //Start

    private void Update()
    {
        Collect();
    }

    void Collect()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && !pickedUp)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = fpCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, distanceToItem))
            {
                if(hit.collider.gameObject == gameObject)
                {
                    Debug.Log("pickedup");
                    pickedUp = true;
                    StartCoroutine("AddItem");
                    //play sound here
                }
            }
        }
    } //Collect


    IEnumerator AddItem()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        //GameObject i = Instantiate(itemIcon);
        //i.transform.SetParent(invScript.inventoryPanel.transform);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    } //AddItem


} //class
```

By the way, since this is always running on every instance of `PickUpItems`, it will result in more computation as more instances are in the scene. Consider refactoring so that you run the `Physics.Raycast` exactly once every frame, maybe in a script attached to the player, and then if it hits a gameObject with `PickUpItems`, it tells that item to get picked up. More efficient in crowded scenes that way.